# How to play every album of an artist in sequence with the new music app?

Tags: music, ios, music.app

With the old music app I was able to select an artist and listen to every music by album. Now it orders the musics alphabetically and unless I want to hear the same music N times I have to use shuffle.

Is is possible to just select an artist and play every album with making a playlist?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this natively without playlists or queuing, but Picky (https://appsto.re/us/e-uOD.i) can do it.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

My iPhone is running iOS 9, and things are little different from previous version of iOS and the native music app. here i want to listen to Paramore, play 1 song and then click the three dots at the end of every album/singles and select add next or play next so that it will play as you want them orderly.